# How to visualize trailing blanks and any tab characters (even non trailing)

Tags: whitespace-mode

I would like to visualize tabs. Here, I almost succeeded:

```
(setq whitespace-style '(face trailing tabs lines-tail indentation))
```

- `face` is needed for other things to work;
- `trailing` visualizes trailing blanks just perfectly;
- `tabs` doesn't work;
- `lines-tail` highlights tails of too long lines — perfect;
- `indentation` according to documentation should show tabs when you've set up Emacs to indent with spaces and vice versa.

Why `tabs` doesn't work? Two possibilities:

- It's tricky. To make it work you need extra knowledge.
- Well, it's just currently broken.

Before reporting a bug, I decided to ask if anyone succeeded in visualizing tabs at any position (I'm particularly interested in indentation). Basically, if there is a tab character in file, I want to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to check in this case:

1. Does `whitespace-tab` have non-transparent background? Use <kbd>M-x list-faces-display</kbd> to check faces. In my case `solarized-dark` had `whitespace-tab` with transparent background.
2. Remove `indentation` because it turns out that this thing has the ability to override tab face in indentation with indentation face which was also transparent.